# Which protocol method call after created UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

**Sorry for asking this type of simple question here.**

But I am new at iOS development :( also i am  trying on google for find my answer but i don't get it.

**My Question is that which protocol method of `UITableView` is call after created whole TableView ?**

i mean when create `UITableView` then call `UITableViewDataSource` method such like ,

**Configuring a Table View**

```
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  required method
– numberOfSectionsInTableView:
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  required method
– sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:
– tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:
– tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:titleForFooterInSection:
```

etc...

But i want to know which method of UITableView call after creating whole TableView (OR call above methods) without any UITableView interaction ?

so, please help me

Comment: for wat do u want to call it ?

Comment: i want to add all String in UITextFields that are subview of cell.contentView

Answer (score 1):

Since the order is not specified in Apple's documentation, you cannot safely assume that they will always be called in the same order and it is generally not a good idea to make such assumptions in your implementation.

For example, cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called for all rows. It is only called for visible rows and then called for additional rows as the user scrolls to them. Old rows are also destroyed as they go off the screen and it will request the cells again if the user scrolls back up.

But in general we can assume some Order of call:

```
– numberOfSectionsInTableView:        (...Optional method...)
– sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:     (...Optional method...)
– tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:  (...Optional method...)
– tableView:titleForFooterInSection:  (...Optional method...)
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:    (...Compulsory method...)
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (...Compulsory method...)
```

Comment: thanks for helping me :) i know about above method but i want to any method have UITableView that call after created whole UITableView ??  ...........THANKS FRieND :)

Answer (score 1):

For creation of UITable all required method has to called. i.e.

```
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

Off course these are datasource method . But after creation of the table none of this method called until you reload the table.
 If you want method that called after creation of the tableview you have to look for delegate methods like:

```
– tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
```