# When do UITableViewDataSource methods get called?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am aware that a UITableView's data source methods are requested when `reloadData` is executed on the table view.

I am curious as to when they are requested in other circumstances.

Is it on initialization of a table view?
Is it when the table view is added to the view hierarchy?
What about if I load a table view directly from a nib before adding to the view hierarchy? Are the data source methods requested after awakeFromNib?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576860/which-protocol-method-call-after-created-uitableview

Comment: Hey Bhargavi, thanks for the link. That doesn't entirely answer my question. That post suggests the order in which the methods may be executed. In any case, I think I found the answer I'm looking for in the Apple docs for UITableView. _UITableView overrides the layoutSubviews method of UIView so that it calls reloadData only when you create a new instance of UITableView or when you assign a new data source._